# Using jquery and css to make a liquid layout

Tags: jquery, css

At the moment I have a main product image with alt images to the right of it, I am using jquery to calculate the height of my main image and then didvide out my alt images to get there height because I will not know how many alts there will be. My question is how can I take the same approach but make the whole layout liquid. Here is a link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/7112/

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by layout liquid?

Comment: That all of the widths and heights of all the elements will stretch/grow as the screen size gets larger

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? I only noticed that the divs that hold the thumbs have a gap between the thimbnail and the closing of the div and that the heights do not change when you change the window height. Is this what worries you?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things going on here...First thing you need to know is that borders contribute to an element's overall width.  So if you have a Parent DIV with two children div's the children divs cannot both be width=50% AND have a border AND float left without wrapping.  I would recommend putting a temporary border: 1px solid red (or another color) on your .photoWrap and .altWrap and .assestWrap so you can see what is going on with the sizes.

Second thing you need to know is that setting widths by % are relative to the container they are in.  So if you have:

```
<div id="A">
   <div id="B">...</div>
   <div id="C">
      <div class="D">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and you set .D { width: 20%; } that means D's width is 20% of C which is already a percentage of A.

Another thing you need to now is that when you set only a width on an image the aspect ratio of the image will remain intact.  What that means that if the images are not square you're going to have a right div that is taller than your main image.

And you're setting a margin:3% which is why your divs have a space between them